# How can I map bits in a byte to turn on or off a pin?

Tags: c, embedded

I have a byte of data as input and each bit represents the state of an led. The pins that control the leds are spread out and on different ports.

I have C code that changes the state of 6 leds. these leds are mapped to 6 pins which are in the same port and are sequentially assigned.

Im porting this code to a micro where the available pins aren't in the same port.

thanks

Comment: You need to know about basic bitwise operations such as shifting and masking. No, you can't do it with tables (only).

Comment: Which micro, and what C compiler?

Comment: You may find this question at StackOverflow helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/161052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I meant:

```
static led_map_t led_map[LED_COUNT] =
{/*     GPIO, Port control, Bit Mask    */
        PTB,  PORTB,        PTB8,   //LED1
        PTD,  PORTD,        PTD2,   //LED2
        PTD,  PORTD,        PTD3,   //LED3
        PTD,  PORTD,        PTD4,   //LED4
        PTD,  PORTD,        PTD11,  //LED5
        PTC,  PORTC,        PTC17,  //LED6
};

static void update_mapped_leds(uint8_t bit_reg)
{
    uint8_t index;

    for (index = 0; index < LED_COUNT; index++)
    {
        if (Is_Bit_Set(bit_reg, index))
        {
            led_map[index].port_io_ptr->PSOR |= (1 << led_map[index].bit_mask);
        }
        else
        {
            led_map[index].port_io_ptr->PCOR |= (1 << led_map[index].bit_mask);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least add the type definition of `led_map_t`. And there is no need to set the size of the array `led_map`, except for this one case to be detected at compile-time: more entries than defined in the size. You can simply write `static led_map_t led_map[] = ...` for automatic sizing. The `for`-loop will then be written as `for (index = 0; index < sizeof led_map / sizeof led_map[0]; index++)`. Additionally I would add the `const` modifier to the array since you wont change the contents.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can do this without functions. Just write the code that accomplishes what you want. I suppose you could use a table but I can't imagine how or why.

In C, you manipulate bits and bit fields using the `&` bitwise-AND, `|` bitwise-OR, `^` bitwise XOR, and `<<` `>>` bitwise shift operators.